# Mac OS screen as video source

Tags: objective-c, macos, video

I'm want to create application for OSX where I can record video from webcam and from screen(at the same time or in succession).
In Windows I can use DirectShow and ScreenCapture filter as video source, but in Mac OS we have no DirectShow and filters.
Is it possible to create something like ScreenCapture filter in windows for Mac OS?
Maybe it's must be some video kext or something else.

Can anybody help me with this question?

Thank you.

Comment: I have update my answer with links with Apple Sample Projects that do the two things you want i.e recode the screen and record from a camera. Hopefully this will get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple have an example of recording the screen. [Technical Q&A QA1740](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1740/_index.html)

> How to capture screen activity to a movie file using AV Foundation on
>   Mac OS X Lion
>
> Q:  How do I capture screen activity to a Quicktime movie on Mac OS X
>   Lion?

I am on mountain lion. With a little tweaking the example works.

---

EDIT 1* here is a second example from Apple [AVScreenShack](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html). Sample Project

Note:I could not get the AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh  to work for high quality in either example.  Apart from  if I set the input's cropRect width & height to anything below 700x700 in the first example.

But the AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto worked fine and captured the whole screen in good quality.

---

Edit 2*

Here is Apples sample to record using a device such as an iMac Camera. The sample Project works from the get go.
[AVRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Also thanx about AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto preset trick.

Answer (score -1):

have look at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html). Get many images and make a video from that images.

Answer (score -2):

Open the `QuickTimePlayer` (at home in the `Applications` folder) click: File --> try: `New Screen Recording` (and play with the other two menu items).

[image]

I think it is close to what you want to do.

A new panel will open; play with the triangle at the right side:

[image]

Comment: So if he or she wants to develop a screen-capture application of their own, use QuickTimeX, instead, and that's your solution?